# Lookup data from excel table with several conditions in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with data on Excel Worksheet;
here is a link to the image [IMAGE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B40fd-B4hpJAMTY5WkRzdFhYbDA)

I'm writing a function function *myFunction(isin as variant, dt as date)* in VBA, which should find the value which corresponds to isin and the most recent date to the given date dt (without being after the date dt).

Here is a sample of my code.

```
Function myFunction(isin As Variant, dt As Date)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Dim last_row As Integer
last_row1 = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

myFunction = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(isin, ws.Range("A1:C" & last_row1), 3, False)

End Function
```

This uses the Excel's vlookup function, but I can't imagine how should I find the targeted value.

Comment: for starters, make sure your date is stored as an excel date serial and not a date formatted as text.  I use isnumber() or istext() to test.

Comment: In order to use VLOOKUP, your index value you are searching for has to be to the left of any data you want to return.  In you example its to the right if I read your table correctly.  In this case you would want to use an excel formula of INDEX() and MATCH().  however their may be some prettier ways of doing this purely through VBA.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm looking for a way to do this within the vba, not with excel functions. The Vlookup in this code is not a solution. )

Comment: correct, you would need to substitue the a combination of INDEX/MATCH into your worksheet function line

Comment: As to what you want to target its the MAX() of your date column provided its not a date stored as text.

Comment: yes, but this should be multiconditional, as the data is not only for the name "LPS_1", also the name can be repeated )

Comment: Just reviewing your Data in your image, that is a reference set to search through?  Somewhere else maybe another sheet you are going to tell it which isin you want to find the most recent value for?  or do you want to return the most recent value for each unique isin?

Comment: IF it has the same name, according to my interpretation of your question you are just looking for the most recent value.  Are you saying you can have the same name and the same date but different values?

Comment: I want to make this table unique for all 'isin'-s. What do you mean about the another sheet ?

Comment: OK one last stab at understanding your question.  You want to search through your data table and find the results that match the ISIN name.  Then based on those results, you want to find the most recent date and second most recent date.  Then based on those two dates take the corresponding value and find the difference?

Comment: I did not know if you were using your Function on the same sheet as your table of data.  Sometime people work all on the same sheet, sometimes they work on a different worksheet than where their data is stored.  Was just trying to clarify things

Comment: it's something like to filter all the names by name , and find the value where the date which is the most recent one )), but not the difference

Comment: ok that is back to my original interpretation, you just want to return the third column based on a given name and the most recent date for that name.

Comment: You are right !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still need to test this code, but the concept is you define where all your information is.  Then go through every row and find out which names match.  When you find a match figure out if the date is more recent or not.  If its more recent update your comparison and store where you are in the list.  When you get through the list, return the value of the third column for the number you stored.

now in the case where a name is supplied that is not in the list, I have set up this function to return the value of 0.

```
Option Explicit

Function myFunction(isin As String, dt As Date) As Double

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim last_row As Integer
Dim Header_row As Integer
Dim Name_Col As Integer
Dim Date_Col As Integer
Dim Value_Col As Integer
Dim counter_X As Integer
Dim Temp_Index As Integer
Dim Temp_Date As Date

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'define the your table information
    Header_row = 1
    last_row = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    Name_Col = 1
    Date_Col = 2
    Value_Col = 3

    'Initialize variables
    Temp_Date = 0


    With ws
        For counter_X = Header_row + 1 To last_row
            If .Cells(counter_X, Name_Col).Value = isin Then
                If .Cells(counter_X, Date_Col).Value <= dt Then
                    If .Cells(counter_X, Date_Col).Value > Temp_Date Then
                        Temp_Date = .Cells(counter_X, Date_Col).Value
                        Temp_Index = counter_X
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next counter_X

        If Temp_Date = 0 Then
            myFunction = 0
        Else
            myFunction = .Cells(Temp_Index, Value_Col).Value
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

[image: Example Results]

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I get an error "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed".

Comment: agreed I am still testing it, I posted you a thought process to follow as an interim measure in case you were faster at editing VBA code than I am

Comment: How about to create two arrays for The single name and then lookup?

Comment: thought you said you wanted to avoid excel functions?

Comment: now I hard coded in the size and location of your table pretty much, but there are ways to achieve the same by passing the ranges to the code as well.  but that would be different code.  This is not the cleanest coding, but I think it gets the job done.

Comment: now this gives us the last value, but not the value before the date )

Comment: I thought you said you wanted the value that corresponded to the most recent date?

Comment: if you are searching for LPS_1 based on your original table, what should the value of your function return?  what number?

Comment: No, it should return the value for the "name" where the date is the latest one

Comment: That's why I used "isin" and "dt" in the function )

Comment: the returned value should be for the "isin", and <= dt

Comment: When ISIN is equal to LPS_1 then the latest date is 16/07/16 and the corresponding value to that name and the latest date is 71.5.  I think I am missing something here?  Can you try giving an example of the input you plan to give and what the expected output or value of your function will be.

Comment: OK, In function I should give two values: ISIN and DATE, When ISIN = LPS_1, then MYFUNCTION = value WHERE date <= DATE :

Comment: please give the number you want to see returned by myfunction with the example ISN and the example DATE.   In other words please show example numbers you want for input and expect result as a number.

Comment: OK, MyFunction("LSP_1", "15/04/15") = 78.64, MyFunction("LSP_2", "10/07/16") = 8568

Comment: ok, you want to find the most recent date relative to a given date, not just the latest date.  Out of curiosity did you put the wrong year in your example for LSP_1? If its supposed to be 2016, I understand how to do this...if its actually 2015, I am very confused.

Comment: In other words, Filter the Table by Name Where Name = LSP_1, and find the value where date is <= given date

Comment: You are right it should be 2016, I just followed your picture, and the dates should be sorted

Comment: My system default date is setup as YY/MM/DD.  I prefer the working from largest to smallest.  Also helps with sorting if it ever winds up as a string instead of a value.

Comment: oh and this code does not require your dates or names to be sorted.